# jQuery iterate/loop throught data table on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, datatable, each

I have a table that render results from a database.
Beacause results are a 'matrix', the markup will give

```
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>some datas inside TDs</td>
        <td>Last TD<button class = 'btn-action-edit'></button></td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <td>some datas inside TDs</td>
        <td>Last TD<button class = 'btn-action-edit'></button></td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <td>some datas inside TDs</td>
        <td>Last TD<button class = 'btn-action-edit'></button></td>
    </tbody>
<tfooter>
</tfooter>
</table>
```

For each row inside the table, i have buttons which allows some actions (i.e 'Edit' / 'Publish' / etc.).
When clicking on a button, i want it to do some action.
To achieve that I did the following :

```
$('tbody:nth-child(2) .btn-action-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('tbody:nth-child(2) .detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});
$('tbody:nth-child(2) .close-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('tbody:nth-child(2) .detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});

$('tbody:nth-child(3) .btn-action-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('tbody:nth-child(3) .detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});
$('tbody:nth-child(3) .close-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('tbody:nth-child(3) .detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});
```

but assuming i get 50+ entries in my DB or 1000+, it's going to be a nightmare to do the job

I tried some :

```
$('table > tbody td:last-child').each(function (index) {
    $(this).find('.btn-action-edit').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

but it's not working !

Any ideas on this one ; i'm missing something about loop and/or DOM !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$(".btn-action-edit").on("click", function()  {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".detail-edit").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Update:

As you're loading the content in via Ajax, you could set up a general event listener like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-action-edit", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".detail-edit").toggleClass("open");
});
```

This will then pick up whether the item was on the page when it was loaded or if it was pulled in later with Ajax.

Comment: It works indeed...
and simplier than what i was struggling with ! Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your results are rendered by the server and you just add it then why dont you just add eventListener to the classes and use them relative to the event target?

```
$('button.btn-action-edit').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('.detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});

$('button.close-edit').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('.detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
});
```

if you are loading the elements with ajax then you have to add the listeners to the added content too. But lots of eventListeners are not good, I recommend you to use the button onclick attribute:

```
<button class="btn-action-edit" onclick="itemEdit(this);"> ... </button>
<button class="close-edit" onclick="closeItemEdit(this);"> ... </button>

<script>
function itemEdit( element )
{
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('.detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
}

function closeItemEdit( element )
{
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('.detail-edit').toggleClass('open');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes the elements are loading with ajax and i thought about an "addEventListener" but couldn't find how. I'm going to try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: The .on function is using the HTMLElement.addEventListener,  they are almost the same thing, jQuery just save internaly some helpers for example .off method which can remove event listeners.

Comment: That's what i thought on the first place before choosing jQuery over "classic" javascript. Because at first i started to write a "simple" for loop function but failed to achieve my goal. So i probably missed something.
However that's good to know.

Comment: @Horacio var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('tbody .detail-edit'); buttons.forEach(element => element.addEventListener(itemEdit)); By the way if the answer is answering what you want then please accept it. If not then ask detail, and I will update my Answer to that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it was helpfull aswell and i learned something new.